# How to increase the size of Editor text box in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, editor

I have added custom module and i want to increase the size of the editor as shown here. https://prnt.sc/pbmbfw.
This is my code.

```
 <field id="tc_content" translate="label" type="editor" sortOrder="14" showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enter Terms and Condition Content</label>
                <config_path>ced_csmarketplace/general/tc_content</config_path>
                <frontend_model>Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Editor</frontend_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enable_tc">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a frontend class then style the class.

```
<field id="tc_content" translate="label" type="editor" sortOrder="14" showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enter Terms and Condition Content</label>
                <frontend_class>YOUR-DESIRED-CLASS</frontend_class>
<config_path>ced_csmarketplace/general/tc_content</config_path>
                <frontend_model>Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Editor</frontend_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enable_tc">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
```